# analytics.js Search Field Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to track what a user is trying to search by in our app.  How do I go about doing this?  This is what I have so far. Please let me know if there is a better way to achieve this. I cannot get the bottom to work as it is not tracking any of this info.

```
var myText = "Search Text";
                    ga('send', 'event', 'search-box-1', {
                       'Search Users':  myText, 
                        hitCallback: function() {
                           submitMyForm();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Is `'Search Users'` a custom dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of supplying `'Search Users'` as the key, use `'dimension1'` (or whatever index your CD is) to track `myText`. [Google Documentation on Custom Dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets). You'll have to create the custom dimension within Google Analytics in Admin > Property > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions.

Also, your hitCallback function, the key, needs some single quotes - [Google Documentation on Hit Callback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback).

```
var myText = "Search Text";

ga('send', 'event', 'search-box-1', {
    'dimension1': myText,
    'hitCallback': function() {
        sumbitMyForm();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use site search
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en

Once you configure the parameter, GA will automatically aggregate keywords for your pageviews. No extra code required!